# What's the best strategy for Survival: Endless mode?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I'm trying to beat my high score in the Survival: Endless mode in Plants vs Zombies.

So I'm looking for a good strategy of what (endgame) units I should be placing to make it as far as possible.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Note: I'm aiming for the swimming pool level (see image)

Comment: Just to say, the quantity of zombies stop increasing at around wave 100 so if you can survive that far you should be A-OK.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[This website](http://wartist.hubpages.com/hub/Plants-Vs-Zombies-Survival-Endless-200-Flags-and-Beyond) lists a bunch of strategies. Here is one example of a strategy:

[image: Screenshot]

Essentially, at higher levels, almost all strategies rely on having a constant supply of Cob Cannons to take out the Gargantuars with. The Winter Melons are used to slow down incoming enemies. The Gloom Shrooms in the pool are to damage pool-dwelling zombies and also attack zombies in the second and fifth rows. The Gloom Shrooms near the house are to kill Miner Zombies in the event that they spawn, and the Banana Leaves are to protect against Catapult and Bungie Zombies. The Ice-Shroom is placed in the pond to wake up with a Coffee Bean in the event that it needs to be used, Spikerock is to protect against vehicles and zombies that get too close to the Cob Cannons, and the Twin Sunflower to generate sun.

Comment: This one seems very good, but perhaps consider adding some awesome screens just for the kicks ;-)

Comment: Good idea. Added. :)

Comment: This strategy has no way to shoot down the balloon zombies!

Comment: I think you're expected to use the Cob Cannons.

Comment: ?Most of the solutions do not display back up sun.Where did the currency come from? Despite all my best efforts, I have not crossed 18 flags of survival endless,
please help!!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add something that explains why this works well.

Comment: @GeraldineJain: Sun becomes less relevant as you go on. The four double sunflowers there should be more than enough to replace losses.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis Thanks for noticing that – most of my early answers didn't contain much explaining, so I've tried to explain the strategy better.

Comment: Perfect. I think that also should help with issues like Geraldine's; link + image + explanation should really help.

Comment: hmm in the image you have 2 frozen watermelons in the row. Dont regular watermelons deal more damage and 1 frozen watermelon is enough to freeze everyone?

Comment: @KevinY ofc it does the corn cannon will take care of them

Comment: where is metal pumpkin from?

Comment: @Xitcod13 winter melon does the same amount of damage. the almanac says it does more, but it's wrong.

Comment: @jacen.garriss that's the imitater version of a pumpkin

Answer (score 10):

I didn't come up with it, but I made it through 114 flags with this:

[image: Backyard]

[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8Tya-ZOs70) (not my video):

"Zombonis" in the outside lanes seem to blow up just before running over the first plant, the plants in the pool take care of the inside two lanes. If there's a zamboni right behind the lead one and not on top of it, you may have to help destroy it before it squashes something however. Also watch out for jack-in-the-box zombies that sometimes survive long enough to detonate in the lanes adjacent to the pool.

I pretty much just saved the Cob-Cannons for the big guys, replacing pumpkins as needed due to dolphin riders, and football zombies that manage to make it up to the plants along the top and bottom of the screen.

The one other thing is to absolutely plaster the lawn with sunflowers at the beginning in order to maximize your sun while the zombies are still pretty weak.

Comment: This setup did not work well for me. It falls apart at around 35 flags. You need way more cob cannons.

Comment: What is with the sprikerocks at the back? (I guess they are for diggers but it is worth explainign in yoru answer)

Comment: Video in answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a double sun in front of the outside lines the zomboni's will still explode provided you have an extra gloom schroom more on the inside lane next to pool - in this way you will have more sun for longer. Only thing is when I get to 79 or 80 flags, the gargantuans are just too many - have no answer for that at all. cheers

Comment: By "double sun", do you mean the [Twin Sunflower](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Twin_Sunflower)?